# Saving a .txt to my online server

Tags: java

I've been meaning to do this for a long time. I want my user to save/update a text file to an online server. How can I connect to my server, and then to a certain file;

In php and other languages, you must include a connect.php file, which contains your sql table name, username, pswrd, and hostname.

Is there such a set up in a function to write in your Java code? Can you post some code answers on how you login and then, update a .txt file?

Comment: The server you mention is a DB server?

Comment: It can be both, it is hosting my website, and it can be used as a DB as well.

Answer (score 2):

you want to save a file, so why connect via database?

In Java, you can do the same thing using JSP. In your JSP, accept input (via HTTP Request object) and save the data to file.

To save a file, I suggest you use Apache Commons FileUtils rather than writing your own code.
Use FileUtils.writeStringToFile method(File, String, Charset)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File, java.lang.String, java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: I want to save it to the server, so when I write the entire url, from anywhere in the world, it will just download the saved txt. Would your answer allow me to do that?

Comment: its not clear from your question whether you want to download or store (upload) to server?

Comment: To download is simple enough, that you can just type the url. What I'm wondering is, how do I store it to the server?

Comment: My answer solves this. In JSP, read the string of file from the Http Request parameter, and then use FileUtils.writeStringToFile method(File, String, Charset) to write this string to any file.